# When Cp = Cv + R

Tags: thermodynamics, heat

So in a physics test question, there was this question when is $C_p$ not $C_V + R$?

And I wrote: when number of molecules change. Because the derivation of above formula comes from $nC_p\,\mathrm dT - nR\,\mathrm dT = nC_V\,\mathrm dT$, depending on the variable conditions, (for example under constant pressure, volume and temperature might change, and under constant volume, pressure and temperature might change), there might be some chemical reactions that change the $n$ value. So my question is, is there a case where chemicals do NOT react (that is divide or combine) depending where volume is constant or pressure is constant but do when it is not?

Comment: Another, trivial answer would be, when the system is not just a gas. Or, imho, when it is not considered as an ideal gas.

Comment: Actually That was the correct answer. But then, woould my answer be considered as wrong?

Comment: When a system of ideal gases reacts, Cp and Cv are changing, but not their difference.

Comment: If chemicals react at constant pressure, they also react at constant volume. The yield will be different. But is is not possible to think that a reaction may happen only at constant pressure and not at constant temperature.

Comment: I think.....while deriving this equation we use ideal gas equation PV=nRT which is valid only for ideal gas and not for real gas . So this equation Cp is not equal to Cv+R for real gas.

Comment: In an ideal gas mixture, the enthalpy and internal energy of the mixture is equal to the sum of the enthalpies and internal energies of the pure gases at the same temperature and pressure as the mixture.  So this has nothing to do with whether reaction takes place.  As others have indicated, the relationship only applies to ideal gases.